# Does somebody+have+something really have a passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice

What I read from here: [What-is-the-passive-voice-for-the-sentences](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-passive-voice-for-the-sentences-%E2%80%9CI-have-a-pen%E2%80%9D-and-%E2%80%9CI-had-a-pen%E2%80%9D), some people said *somebody+have+something* doesn't have a passive voice and the others said otherwise even though it sounds awkward. It's ambiguous and I couldn't understand their point. Does it have a passive voice or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's *something*+*be* *had*+*by somebody*, the *by somebody* being optional. An example would be, "Cake *was had* by all," as opposed to, "All had cake." Another example would be, "A fantastic time *was had* by those who chose to come," as opposed to, "Those who chose to come had a good time." A third example would be, "A number-two pencil must be had by anyone taking the test," as opposed to "Anyone taking the test must have a number-two pencil."

Using the passive voice shifts emphasis, emphasizing the *something* being had and deemphasizing the *somebody* performing the action of having it, so in my three examples, *cake being had*, *a good time being had*, and *a number-two pencil being had* are being emphasized, not *who* is performing the action of the verb *have* in those examples. In fact, in many cases, the *who* who is performing the action of the verb *have* isn't stated or even known (e.g., "Nothing was had.").